# How to register new modelAttrribute for same key("abc") and and its binding result, In spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

If there is a modelattribute present for key "abc", How to register new modelAttrribute for same key("abc") and and its binding result, In spring..

i.e,

```
model.addAttribute("abc",objectAbc); // This is already there
//then, need to do, 
model.addAttribute("abc",objectXyz);
model.addAttribute("org.‌​*.BindingResult.abc"‌​,errorXyz);
```

so that i should see new object and its bindingResult/erors in the    view... Please note both model Attributes are two diff objects belong to same class and errorXyz is created using BeanPropertyBindingResult.

Comment: can you explain further, pasting your classes would help

Comment: model.addAttribute("abc",objectAbc);   then, need to do, model.addAttribute("abc",objectXyz);model.addAttribute("org.*.BindingResult.abc",errorXyz); so that i should see new object and its bindingResult/erors in the view... Please note both modelAttributes are two diff objects belong to same class and errorXyz is created using BeanPropertyBindingResult

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple solution to your question.

The Model object holds inside it different attributes as a Map of key-value pairs. With that being said, all you need to do is to "grab" that Map from the Model using the asMap method of the Model. Look at the red rectangle from Spring docs on the Model:

[image]

**Now, all you need to do is a simple put method:**

```
model.asMap().put("abc",objectXyz);
```